# Reason for Windows turning on

Tags: windows-10, sleep

My desktop Windows 10 PC has recently started spontaneously switching itself on. At night I sleep it, but in the morning it is on again. I'm pretty sure it didn't used to do this.

Is there a way to find out what caused it to turn on, other than randomly trying stuff? In other words, is the wake event logged anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look on the eventviewer, go to start and look for it. In the field "System" you could see when something occured, filtering for power-troubleshooter.

Check the powermanagement to define if it's hibernation or sleep-state, in the latter it might be that some devices waked it up.
You might see which devices waked it up by typing in the commandline:

> powercfg -lastwake

or to see which triggers are set up to wake up:

> powercfg -devicequery wake_armed

You might disable the wake scheduler in the gui powermangement.

Perhaps the wake_on_lan tool is active ?

Or perhaps a slightly loose of electric current that might give enough power to the power-button.

Comment: Amazing! Right now I got this: `Windows will execute 'NT TASK\Microsoft\Windows\UpdateOrchestrator\Reboot' scheduled task that requested waking the computer.` which I guess is Windows update. Weirdly it is set to sleep after an hour but clearly doesn't. Anyway these are amazingly useful commands, thanks!