# Is there a way to determine what turned my display back on in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, display, screensaver

For the past year, every once in awhile my monitors will turn back on after having been turned off (From the lock screen, to screensaver, to display off). Powercfg /requests and trace aren't helpful since by the time I run either, whatever did it has already done it and closed.

Is there a way to detect or log requests for turning the display back on? Even if it's just that my mouse moved on its own, I'd kind of like to know what keeps causing this so I can stop it.

Comment: Maybe this could be helpful :   https://superuser.com/questions/1142101/reason-for-windows-turning-on/1142126#1142126

Comment: That is helpful, but it happened again and neither command gave me any information - even running as admin.